# Sigma of product involving exponential

Tags: excel

I have a function f(n) to be computed into Column E in my worksheet. The table is a dynamic range which grows with new input.

The formula describes the kinetics of a dose-response. On day 1, there are no terms to sum. On day 2, there is one summation term. On day 3, there are two summation terms and so on. More weightage is provided to w(i) closer to day of calculation and lesser to those earlier through the exponential term.

Function description as shown in the following image :

Function ***f(n)***

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptSyW.jpg)

```
n = number of days, basically how many ever rows are present.
k1 & tau1 are constants provided already. 
w(i) is provided on each row which is an input to the function f(n).
```

Could you please advise a computationally cheap way to compute this sigma summation over several hundred rows in Excel, thanks!

> UPDATED :

***How worksheet looks:***

[image]

---

I tried this formula :

`$B$4*SUMPRODUCT(D2*EXP(-1*(ROW(INDIRECT($A$2&":"&C2-1)))/$B$3))`

B4 = k1, D2 =w(n), A2 = Start, C2 = n, B3 = tau.

See worksheet and formula assignment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULjI0.jpg

The implementation is not correct because if I go to any row and set w(n) = 0, then f(n) tends to go to 0 which doesn't seem right. Appreciate any help to correct the error, thanks.

Comment: Provide you sample data here then explain what you want?

Comment: Just updated the post with how my worksheet looks.

Comment: Now explain what you want in column `E` and logic to achieve that output. May be there is no `Sigma` function in excel but it can be achieved using combination of different functions.

Comment: Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Suppose you want to get result in E2 cell. Then please explain, how the result will from your provided data? Just put a result manually then explain how it comes.

Comment: `$B$4*SUMPRODUCT(D2*EXP(-1*(ROW(INDIRECT($A$2&":"&C2-1)))/$B$3))`    B4 = k1, D2 =w(n), A2 = Start, C2 = n, B3 = tau.       Can I improve this?